# How to make radio buttons display a text in another activity when clicked in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

I have 6 options that the user can select from and a button that takes them to the next page when clicked. I have two pages like this. After one choice from each page is selected, I would like to display certain text depending on the radio buttons clicked previously, in another activity. How can I do this in java in android studio?

Comment: You can do it in many ways. You can use "Bundle" to pass data to next page. In your case you data will be selected Radio Button. If the pages are different activity you can use "Intent" to pass data.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Eishon, where do I add the text that I want to display? I have edited the question so you can see the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are controlling the `FragmentManager` you can just pass the options as an argument to the next `Fragment`'s constructor otherwise, you can save everything in a static variable (as long as no Views are in there, so don't store the radio buttons there) and access that variable from outside.

Like this:

```
public class MyFragment {
    public static boolean isRadioButtonXPressed = false; //change to true if it's pressed by default

    public void onCreate(...) {
        radioButtonX.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                isRadioButtonXPressed = checked;
            }
        });
    }
}

//from the other fragment
public class MyFragment2 {
    public void onCreateView(...) {
        if (MyFragment.isRadioButtonXPressed) {
            //it's been pressed
        } else {
            //it's not been pressed
        }
    }
}
```

There are many different ways.

Comment: Can I do this for more than one button at once? Like, if x and y are clicked, then display "xyz" in destination activity.

Comment: Sure, you can create more variables or just use a boolean array, or even a HashMap<String, boolean>. You have many types of variables to use. (Then in the second fragment you go if (MyFragment.isRadioButtonXPresses && MyFragment.isRadioButtonYPressed) { textView.setText(...) } or with an array if (MyFragment.isRadioButtonPressed[0] && MyFragment.isRadioButtonPressed[1]) { ...}, for example.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, this answered my question!

Comment: If it answered your question you should mark it as best answer selecting the check on the left. No problem!

Comment: Hi @Fede One more question if you are still available: Can I still do the same thing in an activity if I am not using fragment manager?

Comment: As long as the classes are in the same application you can. Mind the classes' access modifiers (such as public, private, etc...) to be sure that you can effectively access those variables.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using activity, you can use Intent to pass data. Here is a sample:

```
Intent page = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
page.putExtra("key", "This is my text");
startActivity(page);
```

For getting the value on Second Activity onCreate() method:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I understand now.